# What is the trick for swap_pointers to work?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, swap, function-definition

I am doing an exercise where the task is to fix `swap_pointer()`.

Two string should be swapped.

```
s1 = "I should print second.";
s2 = "I should print first.";
```

My work so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap_nums(int *, int *);
void swap_pointers(char *x, char *y);

int main(void) {

    int a = 3, b = 4;
    char *s1, *s2;

    swap_nums(&a, &b);

    printf("a is %d\n", a);
    printf("b is %d\n", b);

    s1 = "I should be printed second.";
    s2 = "I should be printed first.";

    /* swap_pointers(s1, s2); */

    printf("s1 is %s\n", s1);
    printf("s2 is %s\n", s2);

    return 0;
}

void swap_nums(int *x, int *y) {

    int tmp;

    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

void swap_pointers(char *x, char *y) {

    char tmp;

    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}
```

I think that not appending `&` to `s1` and `s2` before I pass them to the function for `swap_pointers` is the error?

If anyone can fix my issue here, please don't give the whole solution! I want to use what you give me as a tool to fix it by my own. If I really can't fix it by my own I will adress this later.

Ty in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's at first consider this code snippet

```
int a = 3, b = 4;

swap_nums(&a, &b);
```

To swap the objects `a` and `b` you need to pass then to the function `swap_nums` by reference through pointers to them. Thus within the function dereferencing the pointers we can get a direct access to original objects and change their values.

```
void swap_nums(int *x, int *y) {

    int tmp;

    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}
```

The same we need to do with the variables `s1` and `s2`. That is we need to pass them to the function `swap_pointers` by reference through pointers to them.

So you need to write

```
swap_ponters( &s1, &s2 );
```

and the function will be declared and defined like

```
void swap_ponters(char **x, char **y)
{
    char *tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}
```

In general if you have two objects like

```
T a;
T b;
```

where `T` is some type specifier then to change the objects in a function you need to pass them to the function by reference through pointers to them. So the declaration of the function `swap` will look like

```
void swap( T *a, T *b );
```

and the function will be called like

```
swap( &a, &b );
```

In your program `a` and `b` has the type `int`, that is `T` is an alias for the type `int`.

```
typedef int T;

T a = 3, b = 4;
```

so the function declaration will look like

```
  void swap_nums( T *x, T *y );
```

For the variables `s1` and `s2` you can write

```
typedef char *T;

T s1, s2;
```

and again the function declaration will look like

```
void swap_pointers( T *x, T *y );
```

and the function will be called like

```
swap_pointers( &s1, &s2 );
```

As in this case `T` is an alias for the type `char *` then the function declaration can be rewritten like

```
void swap_pointers( char * *x, char * *y );
```

Comment: Any good source where I can learn that stuff? Currently learning with EDX and a PDF file to do some pratice.

Comment: @IYSZ I am  sorry. I even do not remember when I read a book on C last time.:)

Comment: @IYSZ - the take-away is that at some point a good book (or several) _was_ read...  Google Books on the C programming language, read the reviews and pick one (or several)  Some sites will have them available as used for greatly reduced prices if that is important to you.

Comment: @ryyker TY, Ill take a look onto this

Comment: @IYSZ Or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/11294831).

Answer (score 2):

Your pass the pointers to the first characters of two null-terminated strings to the `swap_pointers` function.

Inside the function, when you use e.g. `*x` it's the same as `x[0]`.

So you're swapping the first character of `x` with the first character of `y`.

If you want to switch pointers, you need to emulate pass-by-reference like you do with `swap_nums`, and pass pointers *to the pointers*, i.e. `char **`. And use the pointer-to operator `&` in the call.

So it should be

```
void swap_ponters(char **x, char **y);
```

and

```
swap_pointers(&s1, &s2);
```

Comment: I was like "string MUST BE working like arrays" and you made me think now how dumb i am lmao ty!

Comment: So it worked. But i still get GCC Warnings.

Comment: @IYSZ Actually, literals strings *are* arrays. They, like other arrays, can decay to pointers to their first element. Doing `char s1_arr[] = "hello"; char *s1 = s1_arr;` is somewhat similar to `char *s1 = "hello";`.

Comment: In continuation to what @Someprogrammerdude commented about string literals and arrays: String literals are constant strings while the char array is isn't unless you make it a `const` variable. (This touch-bases on whats implied by "somewhat similar" in the comment above).

Comment: @IYSZ What warnings? Please edit your question and add your new code and the warnings, but don't remove the old one.

Comment: @the busybee ive fixed the warning. i missed right naming